# How can I have x many symbols on the first line then adding 1 more each line until it hits the end value with a for loop?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I want to recreate this process with a for loop. What's the simplest way of doing this. I can do 1 to 10 but let's say you have 3 as your start value I can't get the first line to start with 3 symbols.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BqNS.png]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't shared any code, I'll give you an idea as to how you can print the values. I've used 2 `for` loops to print the value. **Although there maybe better and shorter algorithms to do the same**

Just edit my code below to suit your needs.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var start = 3; //StartTextBox.Text
    var end = 10; //EndTextBox.Text
    var symbol = "@"; //SymbolTextBox.Text
    for (var i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        var toPrint = string.Empty;
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) toPrint += symbol;
        Console.WriteLine(toPrint); //LabelX.Text = toPrint;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You can see in the above code that if you change the value of `start` to any number, the value gets printed properly.

Comment: Hey do you also know how to put it in a label?

Comment: just use `your_label.Text = toPrint`

Comment: If you could share your code I can update my example for you

Comment: I got it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Another option assuming some of your object names...

```
 for (int i = int.Parse(txtStart.Text); i <= int.Parse(txtEnd.Text); i++)
 {
      lblOutput.Text += new String(txtSymbol.Text.ToCharArray()[0], i) + Environment.NewLine;
 }
```